# Nodejs Absolute file: url in readfile

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

I'm trying to download attachments from email using imap to my disk. I'm able to connect to my email host and download the attachments. But I want to download the attachments to a custom location. Right now its being downloaded to my _dirname.

Below is my code to get the attachments:

```js
function buildAttMessageFunction(attachment) {
            var filename = attachment.params.name;
            return function (msg, seqno) {
             var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
    msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
      //Create a write stream so that we can stream the attachment to file;
      console.log(prefix + 'Streaming this attachment to file', filename, info);
      var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('F:/'+ filename);
      //writeStream.path = '../'+filename;
      console.log(writeStream)
      writeStream.on('finish', function() {
        console.log(prefix + 'Done writing to file %s',filename);
      });
      stream.pipe(writeStream);
      });
    msg.once('end', function() {
      console.log(prefix + 'Finished attachment %s', filename);
    });
  };
}
```

The above function works and it saves my attachment to my _dirname. How can I save this document to my C: drive? I tried changing the file name to `file:///C:/' +attachment.params.name` and I'm getting the foloowing error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'file:///C:/filenane.xlsx'

I tried declaring writestream as `var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('file:///C:/'+filename)` and getting the same error.

I also tried the above 2 with no 'file:' prefix. That didn't work either. How can I get thid done?

Comment: Have you tried this `var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('C:/'+ filename);`? Exactly like that?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes. No such file or directory error

Comment: could you try this var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("C:\\"+filepath);

Comment: you can use a node js global ```__dirname``` "The directory name of the current module" then use ```path.join(__dirname, "../../file/location")```